# How android set custom font in canvas?

Tags: java, android, fonts, styles

hi i want to change my font size by using paint , canvas in android. My code is here.
how can i do this ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 

{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "RECOGNITION.ttf");
     Paint paint = new Paint();
     paint.setTypeface(tf);
     canvas.drawText("Lorem ipsum", 0, 0, paint);


}
}
```

can any body help me to solve problem ?
i read some tutorials but not under stand .
i have read some post of Stack ,facing some problems.

Comment: where have u put "myfont.ttf" file?

Comment: have u put in asset folder?

Comment: @AnilBhatiya he has used FontCache in which there might be some code he has written.

Comment: @PareshMayani Do you know any solution for[How to display Text in Android Canvas ShapeDrawable with in the RectShape or OvalShape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401981/how-to-display-text-in-android-canvas-shapedrawable-with-rectshape) ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

create "fonts" folder under "assets" folder. After that put your font file in "fonts" folder and write below code.

```
   Typeface tf =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/YOURFONT.ttf");
   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setTypeface(tf);
   canvas.drawText("Sample text in bold RECOGNITION",0,0,paint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
   Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"RECOGNITION.ttf");
   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setTypeface(tf);
   canvas.drawText("Sample text in bold RECOGNITION",0,0,paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the next:

```
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 paint.setTypeface(tf);
 paint.setTextSize(yourTextSize);
 canvas.drawText("Lorem ipsum", 0, 0, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Full setup text in a custom view:

```
    TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
    Typeface tf =Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/BungeeSpice-Regular.ttf");
    textPaint.setTypeface(tf);
    textPaint.setStrokeWidth(7);
    textPaint.setTextSize(Tool.convertSpToPx(getContext(), 30));
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setPathEffect(null);
    textPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green, null));
```