# How to display Text in Android Canvas ShapeDrawable with in the RectShape or OvalShape?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-shape

I'm trying to display Text in [**RectShape**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RectShape.html) which uses ShapeDrawable to display in Canvas.

I'm able to display RectShape in this code, but looking for how to display the String on that!

```
  public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
  private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

  public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
  super(context);

  int x = 10;
  int y = 10;
  int width = 300;
  int height = 50;

  mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
  mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
  mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
  }

  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  mDrawable.draw(canvas);
  }
  }
```

**or**

```
public class ShapeDrawableTest extends View {

    ShapeDrawable shapes = new ShapeDrawable();

    public ShapeDrawableTest(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ShapeDrawableTest(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        shapes.draw(canvas);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX(); // Use getX(int) for multi-finger
                                        // gestures
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            makeShapeDrawable(x, y);
            invalidate();
            return (true); // Handled touch event
        } else {
            return (false); // Did not handle touch event
        }
    }

    private void makeShapeDrawable(int x, int y) {
        int maxWidth = getWidth() / 10;
        int maxHeight = getHeight() / 10;
        Shape shape;

        shape = new RectShape();

        shapes = new ShapeDrawable(shape);
        int width = RandomUtils.randomInt(maxWidth) + 5;
        int height = RandomUtils.randomInt(maxHeight) + 5;
        shapes.setBounds(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, x + width / 2, y
                + height / 2);
        shapes.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);

    }
}
```

**What I tried is:**

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
    public ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

      public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
      super(context);

      }


        public CustomDrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            int x = 10;
          int y = 10;
          int width = 300;
          int height = 50;

          mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
          //mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
          final String s = "Hello";
          Paint p = new Paint();
            Rect bounds = new Rect();

            bounds.set(x, y, x + width, y + height);
            p.setTextSize(20);
            p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
           p.getTextBounds(s, 0, s.length(), bounds);
          mDrawable.getPaint().getTextBounds(s, 0, s.length(), bounds);
          mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);



        }
//      public CustomDrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
//          super(context, attrs, defStyle);
//
//      }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      mDrawable.draw(canvas);
      }
      }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: In `onDraw` method after `mDrawable.draw(canvas);`, add `canvas.drawText(...)`. Do you want this?

Comment: Why would you want to "merge" the text in the ShapeDrawable and not just drawing on top of it (relatively easy)? If you need a Drawable interface, you could instead draw the ShapeDrawable and the text on a Bitmap and then convert the Bitmap in a BitmapDrawable.

Comment: What you want is REALLY easy to achieve just using what the framework gives you by default. Why do you want/need to roll your own custom drawable/view?

Answer (score 1):

The best option for me is to create a custom `TextDrawable` that handles properly how to display a piece of text. Then in your `CustomDrawableView` in your `onDraw(Canvas c)` method you can call it to display the text and the oval.

Take a look at [this answer I wrote recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25420016/2025299) as it contains how to do it properly.

Comment: thanks pointing out the solution ! but unfortunately _setShapeDrawable_ like  _setImageDrawable_  not available for Shape , _OvalShape_  including _ShapeDrawable_ ! in above code mDrawable reference no methods available for setting drawables !

Comment: Sorry! I didn't explained better! But the idea is in your custom view (CustomDrawableView) use a LevelListDrawable in combination with TextDrawable and ShapeDrawable!

Comment: I'm at work right know but if you need more help, I can prepare an example later at home ;)

Comment: My bad I said LevelListDrawable where I want to say LayerDrawable (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html)!

Comment: Glups! My bad, I've been out since your last comment! Let me prepare an Android application to showcase it (I'll update the answer when I have something)!