# How do i position custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

i have created a  custom view but am facing difficulties in positioning at center of screen.

```
public class CurvedText extends View {
    private static final String MY_TEXT = "Select A Mode";
    private Path mArc;

    private Paint mPaintText;

    public CurvedText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);     


      mArc = new Path();
      RectF oval = new RectF(0,0,200,200);
      mArc.addArc(oval, -45, 200);          
      mPaintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      mPaintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
      mPaintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      mPaintText.setTextSize(20f);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawTextOnPath(MY_TEXT, mArc, 0, 10, mPaintText);      
      invalidate();
    }


  }
```

I know i can workaround using setting RectF coordinates but i want this text at center of screen. SO how can i dynamically get the coordinates of the center of the screen? or any other way to position it at the center of the screen.

Adding Declaration:

```
<com.pkg.CurvedText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="center" >
</com.pkg.CurvedText>
```

Comment: Get the device screen size, divide by two, wouldn't that work?

Comment: Would that be perfect way to do so? i mean accurate as centerVertical and other?

Comment: Can you define you View's gravity to center and define its width and height to match_parent?

Comment: @Akagami didn't work! see updated ques.

Comment: See the approved answer. I would really have thought that my remark would enable you to do find out by yourself.

Comment: I waited for a better approach. But none. So i had to accept a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private static int [] screenDimens;

 /**
 * Gets the width and height of the screen. If null is passed, this method returns the previously
 * requested parameters.
 *
 * @param activity {@link android.app.Activity}
 * @return int [0] = width, int[1] = height
 */
public static int [] getScreenDimensInPx(Activity activity) {
    if(activity != null) {
        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        screenDimens = new int[]{width, height};
    }

    return screenDimens;
}
```

That should get you the width and height of the screen. The centre of the screen is simply width/2 and height/2. OF course, you need a reference to an Activity to do this.

Here's how i'm using the code I showed you. In my project I have a Utilities class that contains only public static methods. In that class, I keep a private static reference to an int array that holds these dimensions. Whenever the public static function with the above code is called, I simply populate the private static int array. Mind you, the function accepts an Activity to be able to get the values. In the method, I check whether the passed in Activity is null. If it is null, I simply return the value of the private static int array. This way, I can call this method one time when my app starts (from any Activity), and store those values. Then, later if I need those values again, I simply call the same method but with a null parameter, and I get my stored values back. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: i am not calling this view from any activity :( !

Comment: Where are you placing it?

Comment: Creating this view and putting it in a new package as a class! and simply putting it in a layout! which is referenced to MainActivity

Comment: I edited my answer to add how i'm using this code. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: So, i should store the dims of a device in Utils and fetch everytime user loads that ui? I'll give it a try.

Comment: Anybody have Solution for this [How to display Text in Android Canvas ShapeDrawable with RectShape() or OvalShape()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401981/how-to-display-text-in-android-canvas-shapedrawable-with-rectshape)